# Passing number of type long to constructors

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes A and B and B inherits A

```
  class A
   {
    public:
      A(unsigned long seconds = 0) : time(seconds)
     {

     }
    unsigned long  GetValue() const
    {
    return time;
    }
    private:
    unsigned long time;
   };

  class B : public A
  {
    public:
    B(unsigned long time1 =0):A(time1)
    {         
    }
  };
```

When creating object B x(3) and I print the value of x with this operator :

```
     ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const B& x)
       {
           out<<(const A&)out<<" "<<x.getName()<<endl;
           return out;
       }
```

I get a huge value.The << operator is implemented and works fine in class A

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create `B x(3)` and call `GetValue()` on it please?

Comment: `(const A&)out` What is the point here?. Your code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
out<<(const A&)out
```

You are sending the `ostream` to itself. This prints the address of the `ostream` itself, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Oh yes ,thanks !!!